# MS Word, change time format in "Open file"

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, date-format

I want to change the date format to ISO8601 (YYYY-MM-DD).
But I cannot find anything where it can be configured.
Currently the format is DD/MM/YYYY, but in windows - ISO8601.

[image: screenshot of the word window]

Here is screenshot of my regional settings:

[image]

Is it even possible to configure?

Comment: Have you checked and tried to change your regional settings?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yes, in my regional settings the date/time format is already ISO8601.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the display is determined by the *default* date format for the locale.

Changing the regional settings for long and short format makes no difference. The modern Windows settings dialog seems to have yet another, independent, pair of date format settings, but they do not seem to make a difference either. (if you go to the old Control Panel Dialog, Clock and Region, Region, in the Region tab of that dialog box you should see a *Language preferences* link that should take you there).

CHanging the other date format setting in Windows Registry ( `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\iDate` ) to 2 doesn't work either. I think it's a very old setting.

i.e. you have to choose a locale such as English - Canada to get yyyy-MM-dd format, probably upsetting whatever settings you normally use. That format doesn't seem to be widely used - according to [this link](https://gist.github.com/mlconnor/1887156) the other options are probably French-Canada, Albanian, Bulgarian, Chinese, Serbian and Swedish.

Comment: You are right! Language preferences > Date, time & regional formatting. I have chosen English (Sweden). According to your link Sweden is using iso8601. Now the date format is as I wanted.

Comment: I had to switch the display language to English(Canada), because this will not add additional keyboard layout. At least for my win10  build it is impossible to use date/time setting without adding the keyboard layout. And the Canadian layout is almost the same as US (I cannot find difference).